# Regex test whether string contains digits

Tags: java, regex, string

I wanted to test if a string contains numbers (at least one number)
so I tried out this:

```
public class Test {
private static final String DIGIT_PATTERN = "^(?=.*\\d)";
private static final Pattern DIGIT_PATTERN_COMPILED = Pattern.compile(DIGIT_PATTERN);

/**
 * 
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String passwordOne = "123";
    String passwordTwo = "abc";

    Matcher matcher = null;

    matcher = DIGIT_PATTERN_COMPILED.matcher(passwordOne);

    if(!matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Password " + passwordOne + " contains no number");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Password " + passwordOne + " contains number");
    }

    matcher = DIGIT_PATTERN_COMPILED.matcher(passwordTwo);

    if(!matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Password " + passwordTwo + " contains no number");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Password " + passwordTwo + " contains number");
    }   
}
}
```

Unfortunately both if clauses print out that it contains no number.
Am I using the regex wrong?

Comment: Please tag your question with the language (java?).

Comment: What is a digital number, BTW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with following regex:

```
private static final String DIGIT_PATTERN = "\\d+";
```

Comment: i fount this rege: ^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=\S+$).{8,}$ and thought it is possible to just splitt it up

Comment: There is no need to involve this bunch of regex if you just want to check if is there `\\d`.

Comment: i want to check the whole regex but step by step do print out different messages when something is missing in my password. so i thought simply splitting it up would do the trick.

Comment: `System.out.println("200SSS".matches("\\d+"));` returns `false`  because it only looks for digits in the string, so using `System.out.println("200SSS".matches(".*[0-9].*"));` yields `true` to me because I am looking for atleast one digit in a string

Answer (score 3):

The most basic pattern

```
".*[0-9].*"
```

works for me with your code.

Comment: this worked for me. the ```\\d``` did not work for me

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use

```
private static final String DIGIT_PATTERN = "\\d";
```

That should match if there's any number in there.